# Connect spreadsheets in code (allow importrange)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, importrange

I have a spreadsheet with users, from which I automatically create a new spreadsheet (from a template in my drive) when a new user is created.

I then grant the new user permission to look at the spreadsheet and sent it to him via email.

Here's the question:

In the template I have a field that references another spreadsheet via Importrange("spreadsheeturl"). Now everytime a new spreadsheet is created I need to open the sheet with my account and click on "Allow access" 
in any of the fields that reference the spreadsheet.

[image: screenshot]

Is there anyway to that from my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make an apps script to instantly allow access to all imported elements in a Google Spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178205/how-can-i-make-an-apps-script-to-instantly-allow-access-to-all-imported-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Good question- I honestly couldn't say.  But if the point is just to port data from an existing spreadsheet into this new one, you could use code to replace the importrange.

Something like

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
data = openById("string-id"),
value = data.getRange(range).getValue();
ss.getSheetByName("sheet-name").getRange(range).setValue(value);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It needs to be a reference since the value from the original sheet is subject to change.

Comment: I see your problem.  But importranges are unreliable- I used to use them, but they are extremely prone to throwing errors at random times.  You could use the above method, with a trigger to rerun it once a day or so, so that the spreadsheet is kept up-to-date.