# programatically connect two Spreadsheets so you can IMPORTRANGE without having to manually authorize

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace, importrange

First, this is for Enterprise G-Suite. Sharing/publishing outside of work domain is disabled.

This is my setup:

1. template Spreadsheet in a folder on team drive 1
2. destination Spreadsheet in a folder on team drive 1
3. destination folder on a team drive 2

I have a script that:

1. Copies #1 to #3
2. Adds an `IMPORTRANGE` function to #2 that pulls data from the new file created in #3

Now, when I go into #2, I see the import range function there is an error and I have to authorize the sheets: "You need to connect these sheets.". Below is a screenshot:

[image]

If I click "Allow access" it works and does pull data from the newly copied file.

What I am wondering is if there is a way to authorize the access programatically in my code so I don't have to open #2 and manually authorize?

```
var sFileID = "ID of template Spreadsheet in a folder on team drive 1";
var dFileID = "ID destination Spreadsheet in a folder on team drive 1";
var dFolderID = "ID of destination folder on a team drive 2";

// get the 2 files and the folder
var sFile = DriveApp.getFileById(sFileID);
var dFile = DriveApp.getFileById(dFileID);
var dFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dFolderID);

// copy the template file to the destination folder
var nFile = sFile.makeCopy("test", dFolder);

// open the destination spreadsheet
var dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dFileID);

// get the sheet
var ds = dss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

// append a new row with the IMPORTRANGE function pulling from the new file
ds.appendRow(['=IMPORTRANGE("' + nFile.getId() + '", "Sheet1!A2:D2")']);

SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to automatically authorize IMPORTRANGE. Google Apps Script either Google Sheets API have a method that does this.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32474761/1595451) one alternative is to share the source spreadsheet with anyone with the link.

Related

- [How can I make an apps script to instantly allow access to all imported elements in a Google Spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25178205/1595451)
- [How to allow access for importrange function via apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28038768/1595451)